# Dynamically create an element in google desktop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-desktop

How can I dynamically create elements, like labels and such, using the google desktop API? Put differently, how can I duplicate the browser's:

```
document.createElement('br');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed answer. Look at:

http://code.google.com/apis/desktop/docs/gadget_apiref.html#view

for

appendElement(string xml) 
Parses the provided element definition, given in XML format, and appends the element as the last child of this view. 
Returns The new element

Usage example is as follows:

```
var divXml = "<div enabled='true' height='40' name='divMsg1' width='243' x='0' y='40' background='#FFFFFF'><label height='20' name='lblName1' width='190' x='0' y='0'>Name</label><label height='20' name='lblStatus1' width='50' x='190' y='0' align='right' color='#FF0000'>Status</label><label height='20' name='lblDate1' width='150' x='0' y='21' size='8'>Date</label></div>";
view.appendElement(divXml);
```

I am using this piece of code in my own Gadget but made a few changes to make it generic enough to post here. It should hopefully work as is.